# Xamarin Android: using ScrollView makes widget not working

Tags: android, xamarin, widget

I've been trying to develop simple Android Widget using Xamarin.

When using LinearLayout with contents inside it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px">
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

everything works fine, but of course when I add for example 10 buttons I cannot scroll my widget to get access to every button.

When adding scroll view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px">
    <ScrollView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="vertical"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <Button
                p1:text="Button"
                p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                p1:id="@+id/button1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

my widget cannot run (`Problem loading widget`).

I haven't add any back-end code yet. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Add the error which is generated, without that info helping will be impossible.

Comment: How to access error? I got only `Problem loading widget` when running widget on my phone

Comment: Try to debug your app and see the output, else use the monitor tool on the android SDK and look for messages from your app